# Can't access Drools in Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, drools, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-instances

When i run docker.io/jboss/drools-workbench-showcase locally it works fine at localhost:8080/business-central per [instructions](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/drools-workbench-showcase)

Trying to run it in Azure container instance using the following terraform configuration it times out.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "drools-jrg" {
  name     = "drools-jrg"
  location = "eastus"
}

resource "azurerm_container_group" "drools1-jrg" {
  name                = "drools1-jrg"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.drools-jrg.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.drools-jrg.name}"
  ip_address_type     = "public"
  dns_name_label      = "mydroolsurlyyy-${azurerm_resource_group.drools-jrg.name}"
  os_type             = "Linux"

  container {
    name   = "drools-workbench-showcase-jrg-1"
    image  = "docker.io/jboss/drools-workbench-showcase"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"

    ports {
      port     = 8080
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
    ports {
      port     = 8081
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }
```

When i go to the portal, it appears to be created fine.  No errors on CLI either.  I tried this manually to on the portal.  Giving terraform config as i think it would help.

Only thing im wondering is if its not allowing HTTP over 8080?

Can anyone help explain why i can't business central can't be loaded over:

http://mydroolsurlyyy--drools-jrg.eastus.azurecontainer.io:8080/business-central

*dnsnamechanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in the docker image, you need to expose the ports 8080 and 8001, not the 8081. Additional, there is nothing wrong if you change the port. Just a piece of advice, you should request for bigger CPU and memory, for example, 2 for CPU and 4 for memory, then it will work well.